# es6 filter array based on another array with out mutating

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, immutability

filtering arrays has been asked here a lot but none of the questions and answers i found took in consideration the 2 conditions i need:
1. not mutating the objects.
2. using es6 (ecmascript2015) and above.
3. get a new array that holds the overriten objects and values.

i actually have an answer to one part of my question and that is how to filter but it feels like a hack rather than a real solution, the second part is how to get the full original array with the changes from the second array but without mutating the objects.

This is my code, as you can see i'm assigning the `{dirty:true}` explicitly rather than pass the object from the array it self:

```
    const docPositions = [
    {
      active : false,
      dirty : false,
      key : "somekey2"
    },
    {
      active : false,
      dirty : false,
      key : "somekey1"
    },
    {
      active : false,
      dirty : false,
      key : "somekey4"
    },
    {
      active : false,
      dirty : false,
      key : "somekey3"
    }
  ]
const dirtyPositions = [
  {
      active : false,
      dirty : true,
      key : "somekey1"
  },
    {
      active : false,
      dirty : true,
      key : "somekey3"
  } 
]

let result = docPositions.filter(x=> dirtyPositions.some(y=>y.key == x.key))
                         .map(o=> Object.assign({},o,{dirty:true}));

console.log(result);
```

result:

```
Array [
  Object {
    "active": false,
    "dirty": true,
    "key": "somekey1"
  },
  Object {
    "active": false,
    "dirty": true,
    "key": "somekey3"
  }
]
```

desired result:

```
 Array   [
    {
      active : false,
      dirty : false,
      key : "somekey2"
    },
    {
      active : false,
      dirty : true,
      key : "somekey1"
    },
    {
      active : false,
      dirty : false,
      key : "somekey4"
    },
    {
      active : false,
      dirty : true,
      key : "somekey3"
    }
  ]
```

Comment: The output you list at the end is not what the code produces. You probably did not copy this from the actual output. Hint: `dirty` should be `true` in the output, while `active` should not.

Comment: I don't think you can avoid additional mapping if you want to set `dirty` to true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do it by using `find` on the dirty positions, which either returns `undefined` or the dirty object. If you put that as third argument to `Object.assign` together with the matching `docPosition` in second position, you will get the desired result:

```
const result = docPositions.map(
    x => Object.assign({}, x, dirtyPositions.find(y=>y.key == x.key)));
```

```js
const docPositions = [
    {
      active : false,
      dirty : false,
      key : "somekey2"
    },
    {
      active : false,
      dirty : false,
      key : "somekey1"
    },
    {
      active : false,
      dirty : false,
      key : "somekey4"
    },
    {
      active : false,
      dirty : false,
      key : "somekey3"
    }
  ]
const dirtyPositions = [
  {
      active : false,
      dirty : true,
      key : "somekey1"
  },
    {
      active : false,
      dirty : true,
      key : "somekey3"
  } 
]

const result = docPositions.map(
    x => Object.assign({}, x, dirtyPositions.find(y=>y.key == x.key)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

#### For large arrays...

The above has a time complexity of *O(n²)*, so  when both arrays are large, then performing `.find()` on each `.map()` iteration may become too costly. In that case it is better to first turn the `dirtyPositions` array into a `Map`. To keep with the *functional programming* style, you could pass that Map as the context to `.map()` so it is available as `this`. For that you need to use the standard `function` notation though:

```
const result = docPositions.map(function (x) { 
    return Object.assign({}, x, this.get(x.key));
}, new Map(dirtyPositions.map(y=>[y.key, y])));
```

This will run in *O(n)*, as the `get()` operation is in most implementations near-constant in time.

```js
const docPositions = [
    {
      active : false,
      dirty : false,
      key : "somekey2"
    },
    {
      active : false,
      dirty : false,
      key : "somekey1"
    },
    {
      active : false,
      dirty : false,
      key : "somekey4"
    },
    {
      active : false,
      dirty : false,
      key : "somekey3"
    }
  ]
const dirtyPositions = [
  {
      active : false,
      dirty : true,
      key : "somekey1"
  },
    {
      active : false,
      dirty : true,
      key : "somekey3"
  } 
]

const result = docPositions.map(function (x) { 
    return Object.assign({}, x, this.get(x.key));
}, new Map(dirtyPositions.map(y=>[y.key, y])));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Note that the `Map` constructor can take an array of key/value pairs (also arrays). This new Map is passed as the optional `thisArg` to `.map()` so that it can be referenced to with `this` inside the callback.

Comment: my mistake, the question was unclear. i hope it's clear now (thanks for your help though).

Comment: ok, so i swapped the arrays in your examples to get the desired results:  
`const result = docPositions.map(x => Object.assign({}, x,dirtyPositions.find(y=>y.key == x.key)));`

and the second example:

`const result = docPositions.map(function (x) { 
    return Object.assign({}, x,this.get(x.key));
}, new Map(dirtyPositions.map(x=>[x.key, x])));`

Comment: thanks man, though i still trying to figure out the syntax and logic of the second and more efficient example :)

Comment: I added a bit more explanation at the end. Let me know if you if there is anything else that need clarification.

Comment: Hmm doesn't map holds a strong reference and could do me some memory leaks down the road?

Comment: Strong references, yes, but no, the object references in the Map are garbage collected once the Map is out of scope, i.e. after the `.map` has returned. So when the objects themselves would be no longer referenced (by some other action later), the objects will also be garbage collected.

Comment: Can this Map technique be used to find array intersection on O(n) time? `Object.assign` won't work for obvious reasons.

Comment: Depends what you define as the same element. But you are really asking a new question. Please hit the Ask Question button, provide sample data, and desired output, and the code you have attempted with.

Answer (score 0):

This should match as an ES6 answer

```js
const docPositions = [
    {
      active : false,
      dirty : false,
      key : "somekey2"
    },
    {
      active : false,
      dirty : false,
      key : "somekey1"
    },
    {
      active : false,
      dirty : false,
      key : "somekey4"
    },
    {
      active : false,
      dirty : false,
      key : "somekey3"
    }
  ]
const dirtyPositions = [
  {
      active : false,
      dirty : true,
      key : "somekey1"
  },
    {
      active : false,
      dirty : true,
      key : "somekey3"
  }
  ];
  const dirtyKeys =  dirtyPositions.map(x => x.key);
    var results = docPositions.map(x => {
      let index = dirtyKeys.indexOf(x.key);
      if (index === -1) return x;
      return dirtyPositions[index];
    })
    console.log(results);
```